# Change countdown timer text once value is negative

Tags: jquery

I have a countdown timer that counts down days. It works fine but I want it such that, the values reach negative, the text changes from "days left" to "days since" and it removes the negative sign.

How can i achieve this?

[Fiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8Zwc/)

jQuery:

```
// set the date we're counting down to
var target_date = new Date("Aug 15, 2013").getTime();

// variables for time units
var days, hours, minutes, seconds;

// get tag element
var countdown =  document.getElementById("ribboncountdown");
var days_span = document.createElement("SPAN");
days_span.className = 'days';
countdown.appendChild(days_span);

// update the tag with id "countdown" every 1 second
setInterval(function () {

// find the amount of "seconds" between now and target
var current_date = new Date().getTime();
var seconds_left = (target_date - current_date) / 1000;

// do some time calculations
days = parseInt(seconds_left / 86400);
seconds_left = seconds_left % 86400;


// format countdown string + set tag value.

days_span.innerHTML = '<span>' + days + '</span>' + 'days to go';


//ribboncountdown.innerHTML = days + "d,;  

}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the text based on whether days is negative:

```
if (days < 0) {
    days_span.innerHTML = '<span>' + days * -1 + '</span>' + ' days since';
}
else {
    days_span.innerHTML = '<span>' + days + '</span>' + ' days to go';
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z8Zwc/3/

Or you can simplify like this:

```
var suffix;
if (days < 0) {
    days = days * -1;
    suffix = ' days since';
}
else {
    suffix = ' days to go';
}
days_span.innerHTML = '<span>' + days + '</span>' + suffix;
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z8Zwc/2/

```
// format countdown string + set tag value.
var msg = 'days to go';
if (days < 0){
    days = days * -1;
    msg = 'days since'        
}
days_span.innerHTML = '<span>' + days + '</span>' + msg;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if `days` is below zero and change the text if necessary.

```
if(days < 0){
  days_span.innerHTML = '<span>' + days*(-1) + '</span>' + ' days since';
}else{
  days_span.innerHTML = '<span>' + days + '</span>' + ' days to go';    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change the code like this

```
   // format countdown string + set tag value.
 if(days>0)

{
days_span.innerHTML = '<span>' + days + '</span>' + 'days to go';
}
else
{


    days_span.innerHTML = '<span>' + days*-1 + '</span>' + 'days since';
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z8Zwc/7/)